# dplyr mutate, custom function and variable name as characters

Tags: r, dplyr

It's still not fully clear to me how I can pass certain expressions to dplyr.

I'd like to use a user defined function within mutate and be able to pass it column names as characters. I tried a few things with interp{lazyeval} with no success.

See the dummy example below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

# Define custom function
sumVar <- function(x, y) { x + y }

# Using bare column names (OK)
iris %>%
  mutate(newVar = sumVar(Petal.Length, Petal.Width))

# Using characters for column names (does not work)
iris %>%
  mutate_(newVar = sumVar('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can try

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
res1 <- iris %>% 
           mutate_(newVar= interp(~sumVar(x, y),
                x= as.name("Petal.Length"), 
                y = as.name("Petal.Width")) )
```

The OP's method

```
res2 <- iris %>%
          mutate(newVar = sumVar(Petal.Length, Petal.Width))
identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Update

In the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0` in April 2017), this can be also with `quosure`

```
varNames <- quos(Petal.Length,  Petal.Width)
res3 <- iris %>%
            mutate(newVar = sumVar(!!! varNames))
```

The `quos` are quoting and inside the `mutate`, we use `!!!` to `unquote` a `list` for evaluation

```
identical(res2, res3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Though I realized that I simplified a bit too much my question with respect to my actual issue. I just edited the question to better reflect the complexity of the problem

Comment: Ok, I reverted my edits and will open a new question